# Joda-Time equivalent of the following SimpleDateFormat statements

Tags: jodatime, simpledateformat

Would you help me with this?

I've read that joda-time is much 'lighter' than JDK's Date/Calendar/DateFormat classes: [Joda Time library performance](http://java-performance.info/joda-time-performance/).

Joda-time is apparently made up of mosting long number-based classes and so most of its classes are 'cheaper' to create and store compared to JDK's equivalent.

So while I go read up on Joda-time, would you give me the equivalent of the following SimpleDateFormat statements?:

```
    private static final String Y_M_D = "yyyy-MM-dd ";
    private static final String W_M_D = "EEE, MMM d ";
    private static final String W_Y_M_D = "EEE, yyyy-MM-dd ";
    private static final String HOURS_12 = " h:mm a";
    private static final String HOURS_24 = " HH:mm";

    private static final DateFormat mDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Y_M_D);

    private static final DateFormat mDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(W_M_D);

    private static final DateFormat mW_Y_M_D12HrFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(W_Y_M_D + HOURS_12);

    private static final DateFormat m12DateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(W_M_D + HOURS_12);

//    private static final DateFormat m24DateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(W_M_D + HOURS_24);

    private static final DateFormat m12TimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(HOURS_12);

//    private static final DateFormat m24TimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(HOURS_24);

    // This is the format to store in the database not necessarily to display.
    private static final DateFormat mStoredFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Y_M_D + HOURS_12);

    // Used to convert strings to Epoch
    private static final DateFormat mEpochFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Y_M_D + HOURS_24);
```

Better yet maybe some of you wrote the ultimate datetime 'parser' to convert to a number of format patterns (like those listed above) from one provided original string, say: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm". Looking for performance here, you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the equivalent codes in JODA-time:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter mDateFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
private static final DateTimeFormatter mDayFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, MMM d");
private static final DateTimeFormatter mW_Y_M_D12HrFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a");
private static final DateTimeFormatter m12DateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, MMM d h:mm a");
private static final DateTimeFormatter m12TimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("h:mm a");

private static final DateTimeFormatter mStoredFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a");
private static final DateTimeFormatter mEpochFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

You mentioned about performance so avoid having too many String declarations, and String concatenation because it consumes memory.

Answer (score 0):

**About performance and the internal storage format:**

If you carefully read and study the performance article series then you find that the construction and storage of long-based classes is cheap. The cheapest type is indeed `java.util.Date`.

But wait: The main consumption of CPU-resources happens elsewhere, namely by applying conversion of such long numbers to field tuples (using gregorian calendar rules etc.) or internal locking (for example by accessing synchronized mutable timezone state).

The fact that Joda-`LocalDate` uses a long instead of a integer tuple for year, month and day-of-month is not ideal because formatting heavily needs the tuple not the long. The new `java.time.LocalDate` class has the tuple-format - an improvement. So I would not be too enthusiastic about the performance of Joda-Time. It is only better compared with `java.util.GregorianCalendar`.

**About your `SimpleDateFormat`-constants**

It is rather alarming that you have used constants for a class like `SimpleDateFormat` which is not thread-safe. But the good news is that Joda-Time has its own format engine which produces immutable and therefore thread-safe formatters. So the migration you intend is a clear improvement compared with what you actually have.

The formatter class of Joda-Time is called `DateTimeFormatter`. It also accepts pattern strings. Although the pattern dialects are not the same you can at least transfer the patterns mentioned in your question 1:1. Example:

```
   // old:  private static final DateFormat mDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(W_M_D);

   // new:  private static final DateTimeFormatter mDayFormat =
              DateTimeFormat.forPattern(W_M_D);
```

Of course, in most cases you have to adapt other changes, mainly change method calls on the formatter, for example instead of `format(...)` you call `print(...)`.